# Как найти приложение на компьютере через скрипт?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно найти приложение с определённым названием через скрипт для последующего запуска. При этом нахождение неизвестно, но известно название. Как это можно реализовать на C#.

Comment: Открыть проводник Windows, вбить название приложения в поисковую строку

Comment: Как последний вариант пройтись по всем файлам на компьютере и искать файлы с названием `%Имя%.exe` .

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+EnumerateFiles)

Answer (score -1):

Рекомендую использовать класс System.Diagnostics.Process и метод Start().

```
string appName = "notepad.exe"; // имя искомого приложения

try
{
    Process.Start(appName); // запуск процесса
    Console.WriteLine("Application has been started.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error starting application: " + ex.Message);
}
```

В коде мы ищем приложение "notepad.exe" и пытаемся его запустить с помощью Start(). Если notepad не найден, то будет выброшено исключение и поймано в catch блоке.
Если необходимо запускать приложения из разных директорий, можно использовать метод Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().

Comment: Ответ не относится к вопросу, вопрос был не про "Как запустить файл", а "Как найти файл".  
Так же хотелось бы увидеть, где вы в своем коде "ищите" запускаемый файл :)